# Accepted abbreviation for 'synchronisiert'?

Tags: abbreviation

I have the issue that I need to fit the word *synchronisiert* in a column header (computer program) where I don't have the space.

Is there some accepted 'shortened form' or abbreviation that I can use, let's say 8-9 characters?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with _sync._, I'd say. Not exactly an official abbreviation (is there such a thing?), but should be understood by your audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

the  official abbreviation is : **"sync."**

Comment: This sounds ambiguous, as it can also stand for the action *synchronisieren* (which implies the exact opposite, namely that the column is *not* currently synchronisiert).

Comment: I think you should specify what you mean by 'official'. Did you find it in a dictionary? Is it recommended by some screen writers' association or something?

Comment: Do you have a source/reference for this?

Answer (score 1):

In case we have a space of 8-9 characters we may also consider to not abbreviate at all but use the adjective stem ["synchron"](http://dict.leo.org/?#/search=synchron&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) (*synchronous*) instead of the verb:

```
SYNCHRON
```